# making phone number based login friendly and keep phone number unique

Tags: django, database

Sorry for the non-tech question.

I got unexpected request that users of a web (django based) app should be able to use their phone number to login. It was working fine until someone with similar number signed in from a different country but under the same network. That is, the number 078******* exists already and it refused the registration. In fact, the phones are different cos they are in different countries. When country code is added, they do remain unique.

However, during sign in, I really want to avoid asking them to include the country code; must like facebook signin. Whats the most sensible way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the phone-iso3166 package found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phone-iso3166/0.1.1) to link country names to phone numbers.
By using the phone number and the Country code as primary key , you shall be able to handle their registration uniquely .

As far as login is consider, you could try using their geo-location through Javascript on the browser to know which country they are from and authenticate them. This might not be a fail safe method because the user could be logging in from another country. To handle this, you could have a work around in the authentication system to check all possible phone numbers which match with the users entry in the database and try authenticating them all, whatever fits, add them to the session . This rises another complexity of working with forgot password , you NEED to handle this with email and not a phone number.

Comment: Exactly the dilemma I am encountered. Thanks for the enlight on checking all possible phone numbers; tho it is gonna be slow process to some extent, not to mention VPN related headaches.

Comment: Checking multiple users might happen to be a slow process.

Answer (score 0):

You could Geo-location a Country code box in front of the phone number, and they can correct it if they need to. You can even just make it look like a flag if you don't want to overload them.

You will need to ascertain that they are different somehow, and Geo-location is the easy way to do this without having to ask them.

Comment: One problem I'd see there is if they are using a proxy/vpn. Maybe a cookie set on first login might be better?